# leetcode, passes all test cases but time limit exceeded

Tags: c++, performance, memory

this is a leetcode question to return the amount of subarrays that contain the greatest OR total, when doing OR operation on all the elements. for some reason my code passes all test cases but gets time limit exceeded.
what is making it so slow and taking up so much memory? I've seen other solutions that are similar but 10x faster.

My code pretty much calculates the OR total of the whole array, then does backtracking for each subarray and checks if the OR total of each subarray is equivalent to the OR of the main subarray.

```
class Solution
{
public:
  int countMaxOrSubsets(vector<int> &nums)
  {

    int count = 0, maxOr = 0;
    vector<int> subsets;
    for (int i : nums)
    {
      maxOr |= i;
    }
    checkSubsets(count, 0, nums, 0, maxOr);
    return count;
  }
    int getMaxOR(vector<int>& nums){
        int ans = 0;
        for(int i : nums) ans = ans | i;
        return ans;
    }

  void checkSubsets(int &count, int subOr, vector<int> mainSet, int i, int maxOr)
  {
    if (i == mainSet.size())
    {
      if (subOr == maxOr)
        count++;
      return;
    }
    else {
    checkSubsets(count, subOr, mainSet, i + 1, maxOr);
    checkSubsets(count, (subOr | mainSet[i]), mainSet, i + 1, maxOr);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: You pass `mainSet` by value which is going to cost you an O(N) copy for every function call.  Try passing it by reference instead.

Comment: Pretty much all so-called programming competition problems are carefully crafted such that brute force solution fail on time or memory constraints. You need to come up with a clever algorithm. Note, "subset" and "subarray" are two different things.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. yep. I wasn't starting with a brute force when I had ran intis problem. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can cache a lot of data. For instance:

```
or[i..j] == vec[i] | or[i+1..j].
```

So you can readily create a 2d array of all or-values fairly quickly.

So my algorithm would be:

1. Build that 2d array
2. Traverse the array to find maxOr and you can get the count at the same time.

   ```
   for (int index = 0; index < n; ++index) {
       for (int innerIndex = 0; innerIndex < n; ++innerIndex) {
            if (or[index][innerIndex] == maxOr) {
                ++count;
            }
            else if (or[index][innerIndex] > maxOr) {
                maxOr = or[index][innerIndex];
                count = 1;
            }

       }
   }
   ```

This works because when you encounter a new maxOr to continue, clearly this is the first instance of it, so you can reset count.